# Python: How to count the tuple ('a' , 'b') and tuple ('b', 'a') in a list as the same thing ?

Tags: python, list, count, tuples

I want to get the following results:

```
Input:  list = [('a' , 'b'), ('b', 'a'), ('c', 'd'), ('d','e'), ('e','d')] 
Output: Counter({('a','b'):2,('c','d'):1, ('d','e'):2})
```

I have tried to implement the counter as:

```
count = Counter(list)
```

And it could only return :

```
Counter({('a', 'b'):1,  ('b', 'a'):1, ('c', 'd'):1,  ('d', 'e'):1, ('e','d'):1})
```

Comment: Sort the tuples first?

Comment: Also, don't name lists `list`, as it overrides a builtin name.

Comment: What's `Counter`?

Comment: @CristiFati `collections.Counter`

Comment: Thx @pault :d. My mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Simply sort the tuples first:

```
In [21]: l = [tuple(sorted(i)) for i in l]

In [22]: l
Out[22]: [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'e'), ('d', 'e')]

In [23]: Counter(l)
Out[23]: Counter({('a', 'b'): 2, ('c', 'd'): 1, ('d', 'e'): 2})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!. It works. I have googled for many times for learning how to sort the elements in a tuple, but found nothing. Most of the answers are how to sort all tuples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` with `frozenset`.

This works because `frozenset` is hashable and therefore can be used as a key in a dictionary.

If order non-preservation is the goal, then this is a good alternative to sorting each time.

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [('a' , 'b'), ('b', 'a'), ('c', 'd'), ('d','e'), ('e','d')]

d = defaultdict(int)

for i in map(frozenset, lst):
    d[i] += 1

# defaultdict(int,
#             {frozenset({'a', 'b'}): 2,
#              frozenset({'c', 'd'}): 1,
#              frozenset({'d', 'e'}): 2})
```

Comment: Could also do `Counter(map(frozenset, lst))`

Comment: @chrisz, yes indeed. I want to do some testing whether it would be more efficient though. I'm told `Counter` has pure Python bits, while `defaultdict` is all C.